# Derive a column value in my view based on related rows within the data

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have created a view, based on a set of data with truck axle/tire configurations, that expresses information about the truck configuration, axles, and positions (that is, tire positions).

| SITE | TRUCK | AXLE_COUNT_ON_TRUCK | POSNUM | POS_SYNONYM | AXLE | POS_COUNT_ON_AXLE | *EXPECTED_SCHEMA* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 1 | LF | 1 | 2 | *2x4* |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 2 | RF | 1 | 2 | *2x4* |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 3 | LRO | 2 | 4 | *2x4* |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 4 | LRI | 2 | 4 | *2x4* |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 5 | RRI | 2 | 4 | *2x4* |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 6 | RRO | 2 | 4 | *2x4* |

Each row in the data is a tire position.  And several rows in the data relate to each truck configuration.  I am trying to derive, for each tire position, the parent truck's overall "schema".  That is, is the truck a 2x2x2 with 3 axles and 2 tires on each?  Or is it a 2x4, with 2 axles, 2 tires on the front and 4 on the rear?  Or is it a 14-tire straddle carrier, 2x4x4x4, with 2 tires on the front, and 4 tires on the other 3 axles?

I am familiar with some windowing/analytic function syntax like `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY... ORDER BY...)`, and `COUNT(DISTINCT xyz) OVER(...)` but I just can't wrap my head around this.

The *"Expected Schema"* for the truck is the tire count for each axle (`POS_COUNT_ON_AXLE`), with 'x' as a separator.  Simplifying by disregarding the separator, I can't grok how to generate 24 for that 2x4 (rear dually) truck on each of its 6 rows in the data.

The end goal is that I should be able to select from the view `WHERE SITE='CALGARY' AND TRUCK='HAUL1' AND POSNUM=3` and see that the position synonym is 'LRO' and the truck's schema is '2x4'.

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef1a9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MIN` and then the `LISTAGG` analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT SITE,
       TRUCK,
       AXLE_COUNT_ON_TRUCK,
       POSNUM,
       POS_SYNONYM,
       AXLE,
       POS_COUNT_ON_AXLE,
       EXPECTED_SCHEMA,
       LISTAGG(schema, 'x')
         WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY axle)
         OVER (PARTITION BY site, truck) AS schema
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE
         WHEN posnum = MIN(posnum) OVER (PARTITION BY site, truck, axle)
         THEN pos_count_on_axle
         END AS schema
  FROM   Table1 t
)
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| SITE | TRUCK | AXLE_COUNT_ON_TRUCK | POSNUM | POS_SYNONYM | AXLE | POS_COUNT_ON_AXLE | EXPECTED_SCHEMA | SCHEMA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 1 | LF | 1 | 2 | 2x4 | 2x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 2 | RF | 1 | 2 | 2x4 | 2x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 5 | RRI | 2 | 4 | 2x4 | 2x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 4 | LRI | 2 | 4 | 2x4 | 2x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 3 | LRO | 2 | 4 | 2x4 | 2x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL1 | 2 | 6 | RRO | 2 | 4 | 2x4 | 2x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 1 | LF | 1 | 2 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 2 | RF | 1 | 2 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 3 | LMO | 2 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 4 | LMI | 2 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 5 | RMI | 2 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 6 | RMO | 2 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 7 | LMO | 3 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 10 | RMO | 3 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 9 | RMI | 3 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 8 | LMI | 3 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 11 | LRO | 4 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 12 | LRI | 4 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 13 | RRI | 4 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| CALGARY | HAUL8 | 4 | 14 | RRO | 4 | 4 | 2x4x4x4 | 2x4x4x4 |
| MIAMI | HAUL1 | 3 | 1 | LF | 1 | 2 | 2x2x2 | 2x2x2 |
| MIAMI | HAUL1 | 3 | 2 | RF | 1 | 2 | 2x2x2 | 2x2x2 |
| MIAMI | HAUL1 | 3 | 4 | RM | 2 | 2 | 2x2x2 | 2x2x2 |
| MIAMI | HAUL1 | 3 | 3 | LM | 2 | 2 | 2x2x2 | 2x2x2 |
| MIAMI | HAUL1 | 3 | 5 | LR | 3 | 2 | 2x2x2 | 2x2x2 |
| MIAMI | HAUL1 | 3 | 6 | RR | 3 | 2 | 2x2x2 | 2x2x2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LpwLq7YZ)

Comment: Thank you.  I got this working in my actual solution.